# SpeechRecognition in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Did anyone try SpeechRecognition in LWC?

I am trying to implement it in LWC, however, I see the error '**SpeechRecognition is not a constructor**', but it supports the SpeechRecognition.

```
window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;

        if ('SpeechRecognition' in window) {
            console.log('supported speech');
            const myRecognition = new SpeechRecognition();

        } else {
            console.error('speech not supported')
        }
```

**Error**:

> SpeechRecognition is not a constructor

Comment: what browser are you using? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition looks like the `SpeechRecognition` spec is still draft and widely unsupported outside of Chrome/Android Chrome, also this API is a browser-spec draft (NOT necessarily related to LWC) parts maybe interoperable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the locker service documentation this is blocked and will return undefined. Check [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)

Also the right syntax to call this from the Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) is as below

```
const myRecognition = new SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognition();
```

But when you use this you will see undefined and that is because of locker blocking it .

Comment: Thanks, Mohith, I overlooked the Locker service. So this means, we don't have any alternative for now?

Comment: Iframed vf in lwc is all I can think of as alternative